# USB programming, transfer file from iOS device to Embedded os device?

Tags: ios, embedded, usb

I really need to know whether a iOS device can transfer a huge file to a embedded OS device through USB via my app. It is like the embedded os device has only a usb port. So is it achievable like the file transfer happens through the iOS device's data cable, through iOS USB programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the 30 pin or Lightning connectors on an iOS device you will need to join the [Mfi program](http://developer.apple.com/mfi) and use MFi chips in your embedded device, so the short answer is probably "no".

Comment: is it necessary to join Mfi program to connect to already existing hardware?

Comment: Not if that hardware is MFi certified.  If it isn't then you can't connect to it.